# String replace with rules

Tags: 7, rules

Is there a way to string replace with rules?

I'm trying to find some way to transform values without changing a value entirely.

Is there something I'm missing, or should I just make a custom rule that does string replace?

Comment: If you decide to write your own custom rule, please contribute back and add it to [Rules Data Transforms](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_data_transforms) as that module is missing this functionality.

Comment: It really does seem like a bit of an oversight.

Comment: Look at the issue queue. There is a Remove /replace text and Capitalize functionality entry and patch. Maybe that is what you need.

Comment: I'll take a look. Another possible option might be replacing tokens in a body of text.. is there a way to do that using rules?

Comment: It seems you need a text filter in that case. [Token Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter)

Comment: Can that be applied with a rule though?

And that patch doesn't include any remove/replace text, just capitalization. I may have to just write one.

Comment: Why do you need that in rules? What exactly are you trying to do? by design, Drupal introduces changes in texts at display, and earlier keeps what user wrote, verbatim.

Comment: I have custom entity templates with very small changes in the text that will vary slightly. These will be generated based on stock data.

Comment: At this point I think it's pretty obvious that no such functionality exists in Drupal right now, so I'll just write it myself.

Comment: One possible way to do it would be to use Rules Data Transform with certain characters as a delimiter, split it into separate array items and then perform a condition on those array items.

Comment: I wrote a custom rule that takes token values out of a string (though it needs testing still) and which also provides actions for string replace. I'll create a sandbox for it later and use it as the answer, and also tell them at Rules Data Transform so that they can add them it to their module if they want. At the very least, the string replacer works.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Good going. Remember to add it as the answer.

Comment: I will. I'm honestly surprised that this functionality hasn't been put into a module yet.

Comment: Yes I did. I got distracted and haven't put it as a sandbox at all. If there's a lot of demand for it I'll put it up on Drupal.org

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace text about \[node:url\] within a Rules Action?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200105/how-to-replace-text-about-nodeurl-within-a-rules-action)

Comment: Wouldn't it be a duplicate of mine, as it's substantially newer?

Comment: @JackRyan It has an accepted answer, so your becomes the duplicate.  Quality and answers are the criteria for which question becomes canonical, rather than time.

Answer (score 0):

I used this for my incoming feeds, changing http:// to https://

```
{ "rules_http_to_https" : {
    "LABEL" : "http to https",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "ACTIVE" : false,
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "php", "rules", "feeds" ],
    "ON" : { "feeds_import_canada_com" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "node:body:value" ],
          "value" : "\u003C?php\r\necho str_replace(\u0022http:\/\/\u0022 , \u0022https:\/\/\u0022, \u0022[node:body]\u0022 );\r\n?\u003E"
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "node:field-contestpageurl" ],
          "value" : "\u003C?php\r\necho str_replace(\u0022http:\/\/\u0022 , \u0022https:\/\/\u0022, \u0022[node:field-contestpageurl]\u0022 );\r\n?\u003E"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Executing PHP like that is not recommended.