# How to replace text about [node:url] within a Rules Action?

Tags: 7, rules

I'm using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module and have a Rule created that, upon saving of new content, an email is sent out containing the node title, as well as the URL of the node. Pretty straightforward. That said, I want to replace text in the URL before the message that's sent out. I'm using str_replace() but it isn't working.

Any suggestions?

**Update**:

The path currently look like this: 
domain.com/cron.php/newsroom/press-release/[path-to-content]
However, I would need to replace out the "cron.php" from the URL, as that doesn't actually exist. 
So the new URL should look like this:
domain.com/newsroom/press-release/[path-to-content]

Here's an export of the rule. I've removed any sensitive information:

```
{ "rules_press_release_notification_test" : {
    "LABEL" : "Press Release Notification Test",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "php" ],
    "ON" : { "node_insert" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : {
          "node" : [ "node" ],
          "type" : { "value" : { "press_release" : "press_release" } }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : "",
          "subject" : "[node:title]",
          "message" : "We've added a new press release to our Newsroom:\r\n\r\n[node:title]\r\n\r\n\u003C?php\r\n$releaseurl = \u0022[node:url]\u0022;\r\n$releaseurl = str_replace(\u0022newsroom\/\u0022, \u0022\u0022, $releaseurl);\r\n\r\necho $releaseurl;\r\n?\u003E\r\n\r\n[node:url]\r\n",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the description accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to add a rewrite rule to htaccess or nginx config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would transform your existing rule into 2 separated rules like so:

- Create a Rules Component that only performs a Rules Action which is to send an eMail, similar to what you already have in your current Rules Action. But replace the `node:title` and the `node:url` by corresponding parameters to execute this Rules Component.
- Replace the Rules Action of the rule you already have by the execution of your newly created Rules Component, in which you pass as parameter values:

  - the title of the node
  - the appropriate string that matches your `domain.com/newsroom/press-release/[path-to-content]`

With that, you don't need any PHP, so no `str_replace()` either.